# ArcObjects with Left Join

Tags: arcobjects, definition-query

I'm expecting an ArcObjects code which is equivalent to SQL left join.

**For example:** I have the below SQL code, it's simple join to fetch the records from the both tables based on the `ChecklistId` value.

```sql
SELECT  T1.ChecklistId, T1.ChecklistName, 
        T2.Latitude, T2.Longitude
FROM [dbo].[TableOne] T1 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableTwo] T2 ON T2.ChecklistId = T1.ChecklistId
WHERE T1.ChecklistId = @ChecklistId
```

I converted the above SQL query into the ArcObjects.

```py
IQueryDef queryDef = featureWorkspace.CreateQueryDef();

queryDef.Tables = "TableOne, TableTwo";
queryDef.SubFields = "TableOne.ChecklistId, TableOne.ChecklistName, TableTwo.Latitude, TableTwo.Longitude";
queryDef.WhereClause = "TableOne.ChecklistId = '" + checklistId + "' AND TableOne.ChecklistId = TableTwo.ChecklistId";

ICursor cursor = queryDef.Evaluate();
IRow row = null;

while ((row  = cursor.NextRow()) != null)
{
    // ... get and set the values to the objects
}
```

I want to fetch the records even the `T1.ChecklistOwner` column having `null` values. In simple words we can say as SQL `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```sql
SELECT  T1.ChecklistId, T1.ChecklistName, 
        T2.Latitude, T2.Longitude,
        T3.FullName
FROM [dbo].[TableOne] T1 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableTwo] T2 ON T2.ChecklistId = T1.ChecklistId
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TableThree] T3 ON T3.UserAlias = T1.ChecklistOwner
WHERE T1.ChecklistId = @ChecklistId
```

How can I convert the above SQL query into ArcObjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a left join using the "Tables" property.

```
IQueryDef queryDef = ((IFeatureWorkspace)hoja.Workspace).CreateQueryDef();
queryDef.Tables = "User LEFT JOIN Country ON User.ID = Country.ID";
queryDef.SubFields = "User.ID, User.Name, Country.Name";
```

Works fine with left, right and inner joins, but no idea how to make a full join.

Also, you can use several joins grouping them with parenthesis.

```
queryDef.Tables = "((User INNER JOIN Country ON User.ID = Country.ID) LEFT JOIN C ON User.ID = C.ID)";
```